# Stop Work Manager manually, when another event occurs

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager

Am trying to use Work Manager to record a call in background, i am not sure if it will be able stop recording when the call is ended that when it returns to ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to kick off a `Worker` which records a call and starts when you get a call ? If you  must do it this way, I would use `ListenableWorker` and only complete the `ListenableFuture` that it returns when the call has ended.

Bear in mind that `WorkManager` imposes a `10 min` execution window for a `Worker` so this might not be a great fit for what you want to do. Calls may go longer than 10 mins for e.g. Also, this kind of work is better modelled via dipatching the record operation to an `Executor` or via `coroutines`.